# Converting varchar to XML and parsing the XML failing

Tags: xml, t-sql, function, parsing

I am trying to design a query to search though audit logs in an EMR database. The problem is that the Audit information is stored in a varchar column sometimes it is just a text description of what happened (which I don't care about) and other times it contains valid XML (I know this is a design flaw but I can't change it because I didn't create the EMR)

I created a table valued function the parses the xml and returns data but the select statement fails to execute because sometimes the xml conversion in the function fails. I can't do a try/catch on the conversion in the function and I can's call a stored procedure from the function to do a conversion with a try/catch either so I'm not sure where to go with this.

select top 1  * from Audit with(nolock) 
outer apply dbo.cus_GetDeletedAttachmentInfo(Audit.Audituid) as detail

ERROR
XML parsing: line 1, character 136, illegal xml character

Comment: Is this MS SQL Server? What version?

Answer (score 1):

You have an illegal character in your markup you need to have a catch potentially when trying to convert to xml.  I did something like this:

```
declare @Text varchar(max);

select @Text = '<root><stuff>&</stuff></root>'


begin try
    select Cast(@Text as xml)
end try
begin catch
    Select Error_message()

    Select 'Let''s account for ampersand manually by converting'

    select cast(replace(@Text, '&', '&amp;') as xml)
end catch
```

You need to account for things like Ampersands and other characters that are not marked up otherwise the default behavior of cast or convert in SQL server is to fail and state why there is a failure.  XML needs to markup special characters.  Generally there are lists for markup like here (have not tried all of these as this is just an example):

http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html

Comment: It might not have any illegal characters and not be valid XML.  Still converting is a step in the right direction. +1

Comment: I am now getting another error XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: You need to determine if the data is valid XML by accounting for many potential invalid characters.  My example was just the most common example which is generally someone putting an ampersand in a string field.  You could always post the varchar field and we could attempt to solve it that way.  I would write a procedure to do the conversion trying many replace options in a try/catch block.  Sometimes as Blam stated above you just really have invalid xml.  That is problem when someone gives text without putting it around a validator, is it has no requirements to be legitimate xml.

Answer (score 0):

It is not failing for all those characters mentioned in http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html

I checked below two sets. Only set 2 has issue

```
SELECT
    cast( 
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(fldvalue,'<', '&lt;')
        ,'&','&amp;')
        
         as xml) 
    
FROM
(
    -- set 1
    select fldvalue = '<abc>test</abc>' -- Pure text
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '<abc>$test</abc>' -- with $ symbol
    union
    select fldvalue = '<abc>%test</abc>' -- with % symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '<abc>>1test</abc>' -- with > symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '>>1test' -- with >> symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '<abc>test"</abc>' -- with " symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '¢test' -- with ¢ symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '£test' -- with £ symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '¥test' -- with ¥ symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '©test' -- with © symbol
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '½test'  -- with ½ symbol
    
    
    -- set 2
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '<def><test</def>'
    UNION
    select fldvalue = '&1test'
    
) A
```